# Jquery tabs lose CSS on form submit and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a problem and could not locate a solution on the web and so far my own experiments have not worked either. I am using Jquery horizontal tabs and the problem is on html form submit the form submits and the alert box pops up... while the alert box is up and before it is clicked ok the jquery tabs lose all of their CSS... once the alert box is clicked ok the page refreshes and then the horizontal tabs are okay. How can I keep the jquery CSS stable during form submit and while the alert box is displayed?

Here is the horizontal tabs code:

```
<!-- J Query Files Follows -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

<!-- End Of J Query -->
```

Here is the HTML for display of the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Private Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Public Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4">Update Personal Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-5">Update Business Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-6">Advertise</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
<div id="tabs-4"></div>
<div id="tabs-5"></div>
<div id="tabs-6"></div></div>
```

Here is the code for the alert and refresh:

```
// If the database insert fails let's print a query failed warning
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 0) {

echo 'Profile Update Failed';
}

// If the database insert succeeded we can alert the user and refresh the page
else {

echo "<script>alert('Business Profile Update Successful!');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location=window.location</script>";    

}
```

Here is what the horizontal tabs look like when the alert box is displayed and not yet clicked ok:

[image]

Here is what the horizontal tabs look like before form submit/alert-box:

[image]

Comment: Try to run your alert on $(window).load();

Comment: Thanks for the reply veksen I appreciate it! I am not sure if I implemented your suggestion properly?.. but I just tried 'echo "$(window).load(<script>alert('Personal Profile Update Successful!');</script>)";' and had the same result as before.

Comment: `<script>$(window).load(function() { alert(); });</script>`

Comment: veksen still the same result but now I noticed something that might help to diagnose this. When the page is loaded in Google Chrome and when I click the circular reload page icon the page reloads and the tabs stay stable. Now on the other hand if I place my cursor at the end of the URL in the browser navigation window and press enter on my keyboard as the page refreshes the CSS for the tabs breaks for a split second.